# Python, Web app won't save to file. Server Side

Tags: c#, python, web, wamp

If you want a quick version scroll down to the "Edit|1|" part.

I HAVE done a bit of searching on this and can't seem to figure it out. I have a Webserver and a Minecraft server on the same machine (it never takes large loads so its ok) and I need the user to be able to put some input (in an html form), have that input saved in a file on the server, handled by a middleman app (which I've already got done and is in c#) and the middleman app interacts with the minecraft server.

Now everything I either have done before or know how to do. The only problem is saving the content of the form into a temporary text file so that the middleman app can do its magic. I thought about using SQL (since its on the server cause minecraft uses it for stats) but in my opinion its a bit overkill for something that will only be there for a few seconds. (not to mention then ill have to add SQL into the middleman app).

I don't really care where on the server the file ends up since I'll likely hard code the location into the middleman app and it will be deleted after the middleman app reads it. I can get saving to work in IDLE but not in this app on the server.

(I know this code won't take in anything from a form, this was just written as a test to save files)

```
import os

name = "none";

def editFile():
    workfile = open("edit.x",'w')
    workfile.write(name)
    workfile.close()


def application(environ, start_response):
    status = "200 OK"
    output = "Testificate (Feature will be up shortly)"

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),('Content-Length',str(len(output)))]


    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Extra Server info...

Hardware: Sufficiently powerful

WebServer: Wamp w/ Python Module installed on Apache

Also here is a link to what runs with that code [Click HERE.](http://sneakypanda.co.nr/test/test.py)

Edit|1|: I guess I didn't get much into the problem (It was late lastnight when I wrote this). Basically Any type of file will do. I want Ideally the simplest to implement. The above code has no result On the server. It never creates the file nor can it read from the file (if I create it manually). I've been working at it for about a day and a half now. I'm really just hoping Its a mistake on my part. Could the server config in wamp dis-allow the creation of files via Python?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) module, for example, `tempfile.mkstemp()` with a known directory. Have your "middleman app" poll (or perhaps using [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)) the directory for new files, process the file, and then delete it when done.

Comment: Tempfile unfortunately didn't solve my problem, I will keep searching in the meantime. It almost seems like it doesn't have permission to edit files. It simply never changes the file nor does it ever show up. (at least not that I can find). Same result for both Tempfile and "Open"

Answer (score 0):

So I realized what I did while at lunch today. (facepalming myself in the process). The reason it wasn't working was the fact that I used backslashes, not forward slashes. So here is the working version of the above (I used triple quotes just to be sure). I also changed it to be absolute path.

```
def editFile():
    workfile = open("""C:/wamp/www/test/edit.txt""",'w')
    workfile.write(name)
    workfile.close()
```

After that it worked flawlessly. So if anyone else makes that small mistake here is a reminder. lol Thanks to "mhawke" for the reply on tempfiles Its good info to have in either case.